# Prove that a function in $\mathbb R^n$ is surjective

Tags: functions, vectors, formal-proofs

I have a function $f$: $\mathbb R^n$$\,\to\,$$\mathbb R^n$ defined by $f(\hat{x}) = \hat{x} - 2(\hat{x} \cdot\hat{v})\hat{v}$, with $\mid \hat{v}\mid$ $= 1$. I'm looking to prove that this function is surjective.

I'm a bit rusty on vectors, however, so I'm struggling to solve for $\hat{x}$, to show that for any $y \in \mathbb R^n$ there exists some $\hat{x} \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $f(\hat{x}) = \hat{y}$.

Is there another way to go about proving surjectivity? Or is this it—in which case, what's the right vector manipulation?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess $v$ is fixed. Right?

Comment: @JCAA That's right.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Yes! I forgot to mention that $\mid\hat{v}\mid = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I don't know that you're expected to recognize this, but if $v\cdot v =1$, then this is the formula for reflecting the vector $x$ in the plane that is perpendicular to $v$. Which means that if you repeat the reflection you get the same vector back again, i.e.

$$ f(f(x)) = x $$
for all vectors $x$. You can verify this by grinding it out. And once you know $f(f(x)) = x$, do you see how you can easily prove surjectivity?

Comment: I think so. Say we have some $y$. Then we know that, since $y$ is the reflection of the vector across the plane orthogonal to $v$, there must be some $x$ of which it is the reflection. Is that right? It feels a little cheap.

Comment: We can come up with a much more explicit argument. To show surjection, we are given an arbitrary vector $y$, and we need to find some vector $z$ such that $f(z) = y$. Stare at $f(f(x)) = x$ for a bit and pretend someone gave you a vector $y$. Can you use that identity to find an appropriate $z$?

Comment: Right. So we're given a vector $y$. Then, since our function reflects about the plane orthogonal to $v$ the vector that we provide it with as input, we can simply take $z$ to be $-y$. Then we'll have $f(z) = f(-y) = y$. How's that?

Comment: I don't think so. I think you're thinking "reflection of vector = negative of vector". The negative of a vector is the reflection through the center point, which is not the same thing as the reflection through a plane .......(cont.)

Comment: .... try just thinking about the formula algebraically, and don't worry about the geometry for a moment. You are given a vector $y$. Plug it into the formula in the answer and we know that $f( f(y) ) = y$. Can you look at that equation and see a vector that gets mapped to $y$ by $f()$?

Comment: I feel like this is going to be obvious once I see it but I'm not sure it's going to happen on this one—although I very much appreciate the prompting and the pedagogical nature of your approach!

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, and yeah, explaining math over the internet often loses a lot. To state it algebraically, if you let $z = f(y)$, then $f(z) = f(f(y)) = y$. To state it geometrically, reflecting twice brings you back to your original point, so, to find the vector that reflects to $x$, reflect  $x$. You kind of used some of that language and concepts in your solutions, but I wasn't sure you quite had it nailed down clearly. Good luck regardless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110500/discussion-between-nbogs-and-jonathanz-supports-monicac).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f$ is linear,  $f(x)=0$ implies that $x=av$ and $av-2(av.v)v=0$ and $a=2a\|v\|^2$ implies $a=2a$ since $\|v\|=1$ we deduce that $a=0$ a linear injective function defined on a finite dimensional vector space is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

This explicit derivation may be helpful.  Everywhere it is assume that the vectors are unit length.

$$
\hat{x}-2\left(\hat{x}\cdot\hat{v}\right)\hat{v}=\hat{y} \qquad (1)
$$
$$
\hat{x}=\hat{y}+2\left(\hat{x}\cdot\hat{v}\right)\hat{v}  \qquad (2)
$$

Now, using (1) and taking the dot product with $\hat{v}$:
$$
\hat{x}\cdot \hat{v}-2\left(\hat{x}\cdot\hat{v}\right)\hat{v} \cdot \hat{v}=\hat{y} \cdot \hat{v}
$$

$$
-\left(\hat{x}\cdot\hat{v}\right)=\hat{y} \cdot \hat{v}
$$

Making the substitution in (2):
$$
\hat{x}=\hat{y}-2\left(\hat{y}\cdot\hat{v}\right)\hat{v}
$$

The below figure shows the motivating geometry:

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think you have to assume that #x$ is of unit length, do you?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't know that this function is a reflection, you could use the fact that it's linear and then show it's null space is just the zero vector.